# How do you add dynamic field depending on what the user chooses LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I created a component where inserting a record into a dynamic object and its field is also dynamic depending on the user input.

[image]

```
 <lightning-record-form
        object-api-name={objectpass.name}
        fields={objectpass.fields}
        mode="edit">
    </lightning-record-form>
```

This is the js. the objectpass is only a value passed by the event. objectpass.fields is converted into array

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';

export default class DynamicFormFirstEvent extends LightningElement {

        @api objectpass;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The field attribute of the record form needs to have an array of strings.

As the fields selected by User is a comma-separated list, you need to convert that into the above format before passing it to the record form. Do it like below.

```
get fieldsList() {
    if (this.objectpass && this.objectpass.fields) {
        return this.objectpass.fields.split(",").map(field =>
            field.trim()
        );
    }
}
```

Use that in HTML.

```
<lightning-record-form
    object-api-name={objectpass.name}
    fields={fieldsList}
    mode="edit">
</lightning-record-form>
```

**Please note that the field names are case sensitive when passed to the record form.**